# Are feature suggestion/prioritisation questions OK on SO?

Tags: discussion

I've spent a bit of time today looking at user voice, user echo, idea scale etc, as a way of allowing users to do feature suggestion/prioritisation for my open source project (docx4j).

It strikes me that a single topic on SO with the [docx4j tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docx4j), something like, "what would you most like to see added to docx4j?" would do the trick nicely.  It would meet the 2 essential requirements, namely (1) add an idea, and (2) prioritise.

But would such a question meet SO guidelines? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it wouldn't.

- It's a poll, and polls are explicitly *verboten.*
- It's asking for opinions, and speculative questions that ask for opinions are off-topic.
- It's not a programming question, and only programming questions are on-topic.

Sorry.

Comment: Those are the rules for the whole network; they may be enforced more or less vigorously on the various sites, or there may be exceptions; you'd have to ask on the appropriate site-specific metas.

Comment: oops, sorry, deleted my comment before seeing yours.  thanks.